# Replace incorrectly entered dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV data set which is then imported into Pandas. Just a few of the dates are incorrectly entered with e.g. 17/12/0089 (note this is dd/mm/yyyy) or sometimes 12/11/1898 which can not be right as this date is loo long ago.

I need to compare dates so I've used:

```
    df_to_add['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_to_add['DOB'], dayfirst=True)
```

But when it comes across some of these incorrect dates I get the message
pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 964-11-16 00:00:00

How can I replace all the incorrectly entered dates as NaT or blanks?

Comment: `'12/11/1898'` would be considered valid, what would be your criteria for too long ago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parameter `errors='coerce'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert bad values to `NaT`:

```
df_to_add['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_to_add['DOB'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

Sample:

```
df_to_add = pd.DataFrame({'DOB':['12/11/1898','17/12/0089','05/12/2016']})
print (df_to_add)
          DOB
0  12/11/1898
1  17/12/0089
2  05/12/2016

df_to_add['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_to_add['DOB'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
print (df_to_add)
         DOB
0 1898-11-12
1        NaT
2 2016-12-05
```

If need convert to `NaT` by some treshold use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) where by default return `NaT` if condition `True`:

```
year = 1900
df_to_add['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_to_add['DOB'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
df_to_add['DOB'] = df_to_add['DOB'].mask(df_to_add['DOB'].dt.year < year)
print (df_to_add)
         DOB
0        NaT
1        NaT
2 2016-12-05
```